# Game Object follow Player forming as a chain

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game a game object follows the first one when the player touches it and the second object follows the first one. Each object follows the one in front of it, forming a chain, with the player leading the chain.

Here is what I have so far

```
public class ChickenManager : MonoBehaviour
{
Transform player;
bool shouldFollow;
int chickenOrder = 0;
[SerializeField] NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
private List<GameObject> chickenList = new List<GameObject>();

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (shouldFollow) FollowTarget();
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        chickenList.Add(gameObject);
        shouldFollow = true;
    }
}

void FollowTarget()
{
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position);

    if (chickenOrder == 0)
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = player.transform.position - new Vector3(0f,0f,0.5f) ;
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(newPosition);
    }
    else 
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = chickenList[chickenOrder - 1].transform.position - new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.5f);
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(newPosition);
    }
}
}
```

Now when player hit the game object, it follows player but doesn't stay in queue, it's surrounding player instead, how do i fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: debugs are the way to go, however, in followtarget the position of your chicken always seems to be 50cm off in the same direction, im going to guess all your chickens get chicken order 0, so all end up on the same place

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah, I think that's the problem is all the chickens order is = 0. 
I tried to use chickenList.Add(gameObject) when player collides with the game object but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: well, if the manager is on each chicken, then this isnt going to work because the list on each chicken will be empty.  You need a manager on a single object, and then for the collission to be on the chicken and for it to tell the manager to add it to that list, and then you can add 1 top the centralised vriarable of how long the stream of chickens is and have a single list of chickens..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i add the list to the player now and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're doing this in 3D space, your first issue is that you're subtracting `new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.5f)` from your target position so its always going to be in the same position because you've got a static offset, so what you need is a relative offset which would be something like this:

```
var chicken = chickenList[chickenOrder - 1]; //Added this to make it easier to read
var distanceToFollowBehind = 0.5f;
chicken.transform.position = chicken.transform.position - (chicken.transform.forward * distanceToFollowBehind);
```

This will get the position behind your target relative to its forward direction so it'll always be behind it.

And the reason they're surrounding the player (I'm guessing) is because the distance between the navmesh agents is quite small and they're all trying to occupy a small space and end up clumping.

Comment: @TuanDo If A-Fairooz's answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.